# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'connect'

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

So I did `npm install express` and `npm install socket.io` and I brought the `node_modules` folders to my `server` folder where I am using `WAMP`.

Using this as `server.js`:

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
console.log('Someone connected!');
socket.on('set nickname' , function (nickname) {
socket.nickname = nickname;
console.log(nickname + ' just connected!');
});

});

app.listen(8080);
```

and using this as `client.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <title>Untitled 4</title>
<script src="http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
  socket.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('We are connected!');
var name = prompt('What is your name?');
this.emit('set namename', name, function (success) {
console.log('The server got the message!');

if (!success) {
console.log('Nickname is in use!');
}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

the error I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'connect'`

I know I used a different than `socket.io.js` becase I don't know where to get the `/socket.io/socket.io.js`. I tried doing `node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.io.js` which is another one I found i my `node_modules` folder, but that isn't it.

I also started my `server` and I got `socket.io started` so I know that works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you got is because the source of socket.io script (into index.html) is wrong. So change this:

```
<script src="http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js"></script>
```

in this:

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"> </script>
```

And yes, socket.io is a folder into the root server directory and my server-side socket is listening on port 3000.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Thank you, Wilk.