# socket.io client no has method emit

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

using the version stable of socket.io.js from http://cdn.socket.io/stable/socket.io.js and try to make the connection on google chromium and firefox.

```
var websocket = io.connect("http://nodetifications.no-ip.org:3030");
websocket.emit("usuarioConectado", "juanvilu" );</code>
```

displays the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method <Object> 'connect'
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function) jquery-latest.js: 586
jquery-latest.js jQuery.extend.globalEval: 587
jquery-latest.js jQuery.fn.extend.domManip: 6169
a.fn.extend.domManip jquery.tmpl.min.js: 10
jquery-latest.js jQuery.fn.extend.append: 5926
(anonymous function) jquery-latest.js: 6051
jquery-latest.js jQuery.extend.access: 835
jquery-latest.js jQuery.fn.extend.html: 6015
(anonymous function)
jquery-latest.js fire: 1017
jquery-latest.js self.fireWith: 1127
jquery-latest.js done: 8021
callback
```

Comment: Solution:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10589556/uncaught-typeerror-object-object-has-no-method-connect

Comment: Thank's Wilk, whena change this line and run the application the process was successfull.